# How to show timestamps in ms in Ping messages?

Tags: linux, shell, timestamp, ping

How can I change my current Ping timestamps to include milliseconds? Currently it gives me date which only has seconds fine-grained.

```
 ping google.com | while read pong; do echo " $pong  @$(date)"; done
```

If note that the answers should be executable on shell as I am running it on a phone using ADB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're happy with Nanoseconds ... (milliseconds would require some extra maths that would impact on execution time) this would work:

```
ping google.com | while read pong; do echo " $pong  @$(date  '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S.%N')"; done
```

And dissecting the format string we threw at date

```
%Y = 4-digit year
%m = month
%d = day
%H = hour
%M = minute
%S = seconds
%N = nanoseconds
```

For details:

```
man date
```

Comment: Oh, well...should be fine. I can just divide by 1000 when parsing :)

Comment: Hmmm ... can't figure out how to get rid of the space before the period ... echo $(date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S';printf '.%03d' $(echo  "scale=0; $(date '+%N'/1000000)" | bc -l)) ...